# Django 1.6 how to correctly annotate Count() and Sum() at the same time?

Tags: django

Simply description:

```
#for each q in Question , q.votes is correct
Question.objects.annotate(votes=Sum('vote__value')) 
#add a Count annotate, q.answers is correct, while q.votes not.
Question.objects.annotate(votes=Sum('vote__value', distinct=True),answers=Count('answer', distinct=True),)
```

[image]

If I want to annotate Count() and Sum()  at the same time, How? Thus I can do something like:

```
qs = Question.objects.annotate(votes=Sum('vote__value', distinct=True),answers=Count('answer', distinct=True),)
for q in qs:
    #do something with q.votes and q.answers in a template
    #this will be convenient.
```

[Click Here](http://www.kuaipan.cn/file/id_125277263947109359.htm?source=1) to download the test project code if needed.Test function is in raw.tests.test()

Comment: How will you write a single SQL query for that?

Comment: @anuragal I am not familiar with SQL..could you give an example?

Comment: `distinct=True` should be removed from the `Sum` annotation. The QuerySet should actually work fine with both annotations.

Answer (score 2):

With Django 1.11 you can use [`Subquery()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions)

```
votes = Vote.objects.filter(question=OuterRef('pk').order_by().values('question')
sum_votes = votes.annotate(s=Sum('value')).values('s')

answers = Answer.objects.filter(question=OuterRef('pk').order_by().values('question')
count_answers = answers.annotate(c=Count('*')).values('c')

qs = Question.objects.annotate(votes=Subquery(sum_votes),
                               answers=Subquery(count_answers))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for  anuragal . He remind me. I think of the **extra**:

```
qs3 = Question.objects.extra(
    select={
    'answers': 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM raw_answer WHERE raw_answer.question_id = raw_question.id',
    'votes':'SELECT SUM(value) FROM raw_vote WHERE raw_vote.question_id = raw_question.id',
    },
```

This will be OK.