# Django: annotate queryset using extra() and select where date

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I'm trying to annotate each product with a total of the weight sold in the last 7 days.

The [`extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#extra) modifier is used instead of `annotate()` because there's another query that causes incorrect results when both are annotated.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Template(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)  
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='template_product')      

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    date = models.DateField()

class OrderLine(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='orderline_order')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='orderline_product')
    weight = models.DecimalField()
```

The query below results in ProgrammingError: missing FROM-clause entry for table "order". I'm not fully familiar with SQL so I'm not entirely sure how to fix this. Do I need to do some sort of a join on order to get the accurate date for each OrderLine?

```
query = Product.objects.all()
date = timezone.now() - timedelta(days=7)

query = query.extra(
    select={
        'weight_sold': "select sum(order_orderline.weight) from order_orderline 
                        where order_orderline.product_id = product_product.id and
                        order_orderline.order.date > %s"
    },
    select_params=(date,)
)
```

**The conflicting annotations that lead me to `extra()` :**

The below annotations don't work together because the resulting values aren't the actual Sum and Count values (too large)

```
query = query.annotate(weight_sold=Sum(
    Case(When(Q(orderline_product__order__date__gte=date), then='orderline_product__weight')),
    output_field=DecimalField())).annotate(template_count=Count('template_product'))
```

Comment: *because there's another query that causes incorrect results when both are annotated* Please provide also the information on that query.

Comment: You have 3 main entities: `Product`, `Customer` and `Order`. There are **m:n** relations between `Product` and `Customer` as well `Product` and `Order`. If you properly use `ManyToManyField`,  you'll get rid of `Template`. `Orderline` will be still needed as `through` model for the relation between `Order` and `Product`. Please read the documentation about [Many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) and refactor first your models.

Comment: @cezar you don't know the purpose of my `Template` model and none of that information is relevant to my question. To put you at ease and because I know you will be tempted to respond due to your apparent superiority complex.. `Template` holds future prices, contract prices, etc. that are unique to each `Customer`. And please don't tell me I should have included that in my OP because that wasn't relevant to my question either.

Comment: You make a lot of assumptions about what's relevant. Then you try to solve a problem and produce a classical x-y question. If you're not familiar, in your own words, with the technologies you use, maybe you should try to listen to more seasoned developers. Here on SO the people invest their time and effort to help you and you should appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it done with [`Subquery()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions)

```
weight = OrderLine.objects.filter(product=OuterRef('pk'), order__date__gte=date).order_by().values('product')
sum_weight = weight.annotate(total=Sum('weight')).values('total')

templates = Template.objects.filter(product=OuterRef('pk')).order_by().values('product')
count_templates = templates.annotate(count=Count('*')).values('count')

query = query.annotate(weight_sold=Subquery(sum_weight, output_field=DecimalField()),
                       template_count=Subquery(count_templates))
```

Comment: Way too complicated! [KISS Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Comment: @cezar how about you give an actual answer then instead of an anecdotal one. Try to annotate a Sum and Count in the manner you provided in your answer, it doesn't work! The exact method I used above can be found in the Django docs at the link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Django ORM should solve this issue without using raw SQL.
As of your edit the queryset can be further expanded without using `extra`. It looks like you want to filter the queryset. Your approach with  `Case` and `When` is overcomplicated and absolutely unnecessary.

This should work for you:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db.models import Count, Sum

date = timezone.now() - timedelta(days=7)
queryset = Product.objects.filter(
               orderline_product__order__date__gt=date
           ).annotate(
               weight_total=Sum('orderline_product__weight'),
               template_count=Count('template_product')
           )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as explained above I need to use `extra()`

Comment: @bdoubleu That's what you think! You're stacked at this point with `extra()`, but I doubt you really need it. My experience and my intuition tell me that you make a typical beginner's mistake and think overcomplicated. Probably there is a simple and straightforward solution for your problem. Maybe you should describe your problem better and provide more information on the relationships between your model classes.

Comment: Annotate a count and sum on the same queryset. It can't be done as the results are multiplied. Here's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199375/django-1-6-how-to-correctly-annotate-count-and-sum-at-the-same-time)

Comment: You didn't mention anything about `Count` in your question. In Django you can annotate a QuerySet with both `Sum` and `Count`. What is your particular usecase? Please expand your question with all relevant details.